# Disable scrolling on a Scrollview

Tags: javascript, famo.us

I need to disable the scroll/drag functionality on a Scrollview for a brief time. I've been playing around changing a couple of options on the Scrollview, but none seem to disable it completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official way to stop the scroll without unpiping the listeners (something I would not recommend).  The easiest way to stop the scroll is to prematurely end the scroll.

When you create your surfaces for the Scrollview pipe an additional `update` listener.  Within the handler, whenever you want to prematurely stop the scroll do this:

```
this._scrollview._earlyEnd = true;
```

The `_earlyEnd` is an internal variable used by the Scrollview, once set it will disable all scrolling for that touch event.  `_earlyEnd` is reset during the `start` and `end` events so setting it before the `start` event will not do you any good.  The only reliable place to set the flag is during the touch/scroll move (`update`'s).

Comment: I think you might be able to it with a custom event or by extending the scrollview.